# alasql export to excel saving in html format

Tags: export-to-excel, alasql

[image]

In IE9 I get this above window before saving though by clicking save the file is being saved as FILENAME.xls. Also when I try to open the saved file it gives me this below popup message though I can continue by clicking yes

[image]

Is there anyway that I can avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part(The warning popup) can be avoided by doing this below

```
Insert this key in your registry to suppress the notification:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security] “ExtensionHardening”=dword:00000000
You can accomplish the above by doing the following:
1.  Open your Registry (Start -> Run -> regedit.exe)
2.  Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\15.0\EXCEL\SECURITY
3.  Right click in the right window and choose New -> DWORD
4.  Type “ExtensionHardening” as the name (without the quotes)
5.  Verify that the data has the value “0″
```